# Firebase Analytics: export data to BigQuery as a date

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to log events and specify the moment these moments happened.

For example:

```
Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent ("EventGamePlayed", "sent_at", DateTime.Now.ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
```

I would like to know if it's possible that, once it's exported to BigQuery, I could use this parameter as a date / timestamp so I can, for example, get all the X or Y events that happened last month.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't need this, actually. Referring to the [Firebase schema for BigQuery exports](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en), you can use either `date` or `timestamp_micros` within `event_dim`. For example, to find events on April 1, you could do:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT event
FROM YourTable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
WHERE PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event.date) = '2017-04-01';
```

To find events that occurred between 12pm and 4pm UTC on April 1, you could do:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT event
FROM YourTable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
WHERE TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros) BETWEEN
  '2017-04-01 12:00:00' AND '2017-04-01 16:00:00';
```

Comment: This will work, but the benefit of converting data to actual DATE or TIMESTAMP types - is that these queries will work much faster - filter on plain comparison of dates/timestamp can be pushed deeper

Comment: Firebase does not support `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` types in events; they can only be of types `STRING`, `INT64`, or `FLOAT64`, so that isn't an option.

Comment: But when data is loaded into BQ - it can be transformed using PARSE_DATE/TIMESTAMP_MICROS functions to become of right type.